# Изменить форму mesh в MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mesh

Способен ли MATLAB изменить форму mesh. Не количество узлов и элементов, а именно форму с помощью узлов и элементов.
Как пример из одной mesh1-фигуры получить mesh2-фигуру
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

mesh преобразован из stl-модели.